# replace string in php if exist

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string in php that looks like this

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.someclass').click(function () {
    $(this).text("clicked");
  });
});
```

what i want is - if string contains `$(window).load(function(){` then replace this and also the end braces `});` with empty string `""`

But if `$(window).load(function(){` do not exist then do nothing.

Here is what i have tried:

```
if(strpos($str,"$(window).load(function(){") == -1){
  // do nothing
}
else{
     str_replace("$(window).load(function(){","",$str);
     // how do i replace the last }); with ""
}
```

Comment: Why do want to do this (what's the context)? You can't simply remove `.load` directly on the page?

Comment: I am not on page... i am on server with a php string..

Comment: What if `.load` is written like this: `$(window).load( function() {` (note extra spaces). Arguably this can be resolved by using regex but IMO it will be an error prone operation.

Comment: i will always get that string without that extra space.. so you can be sure that  their will be no extra space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is nicely indented like that, this might just work for you:

```
$str = <<<EOM
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.someclass').click(function () {
    $(this).text("clicked");
  });
});
EOM;

$start = preg_quote('$(window).load(function(){');
$end = preg_quote('});');

$new = preg_replace("/^$start\s*(.*?)^$end/ms", '$1', $str);

print_r($new);
```

Comment: i am getting string like this `$str = file_get_contents('file.js');` .... can you please update your answer accordingly..

Comment: can i do this  `$str = <<<EOM file_get_contents('file.js'); EOM;`

Comment: @JAVAGeek Then just replace that block with `$str = file_get_contents('file.js');`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need regular expressions for this one if you can guarantee that the }); will be the last one. If so:

```
$str = preg_replace("#\$\(window\)\.load\(function\(\) \{(.*)\}\);#is","",trim($str));
```

Should do the trick.

If you cannot guarantee that the }); you want to replace will be the last occurence, you will have to walk through your code and count the braces. No other way, sadly :-(

Comment: You can replace that last $str with trim($str) just to ensure there's no extra returns or spaces.

Comment: if their is `$(window).load(function(){` present then their will be end braces too always

Comment: what i did  `$str = file_get_contents('file.js');

$str = preg_replace("#\$\(window\)\.load\(function\(\) \{(.*)\}\);#i","",trim($str));

echo $str;`

Comment: That confirms the issue I didn't state about this answer. Using preg_replace will check only the first line of text. It will not treat it as a glob. It stops at the \n. I believe the /s modifier will allow it to use the whole string as a string and not only the first line.

Comment: where do you put that `/s`

Comment: #is instead of #i at the end of the regular expression.

Comment: Could you put your JS on pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - 4);
```

This will remove the last 3 characters of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Find the position of the last occurrence with [strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) ? Then maybe do a str_replace from that point with a limit of 1?  You should check the modified string with an external call to something like JSlint to make sure you didnt create malformed code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, a working way will be just to test for `(window).load`, and to add this :

```
str_replace('$(window).load', "var functionOnLoad = ", $str);
```

Don't forget to add a call to this function if you want it to be execute. Somethink like :

```
str_replace('</script>', "functionOnLoad();</script>", $str);
```